# SharePoint 2007 Antivirus Protection

Tags: 2007, best-practices, administration, anti-virus

What antivirus products have you used in SharePoint 2007 (WSS v3 and MOSS 2007) implementations?

I've had quite a bit of experience with Forefront Security for SharePoint and its my default recommendation, but it looks like there's other vendors out there that are finally offering coverage for SharePoint 2007, instead of the prevision version of the platform.

Do you think its better to use the same vendor for SharePoint AV that is running for the OS? What I mean is if McAfee is protecting Windows Server is it better to use their solution for SharePoint to keep things consistent from an AV perspective, or is one product way better than another?

I'm aware of all the benefits Forefront is said to have (multiple AV engines, etc), but interested in everyone's real world experiences and thoughts.

Comment: @John Ferringer: Made this community wiki as it is a discussion style question. See more info here: http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/432/what-does-community-wiki-mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A customer uses McAfee and we found that it didn't check for viruses, if the EICAR file was uploaded inside an InfoPath form into SharePoint via a webservice.

Forefront did check there and found the signature. So it seems that the McAfee product uses other hooks into SharePoint.

Comment: It seems that McAfee PortalShield doesn't check the base64 attachments of InfoPath forms. Our customer has opened a call at McAfee, I will keep you updated on the progress.

Answer (score 2):

Just note that whatever Virus scanning software you use, There are some Files/Folders that need to be excluded from the virus scanning software to not affect Sharepoint. This is for Both the SharePoint front ends as well as the SQL server.

More details can be found [here](http://emadmagdy.wordpress.com/2009/07/15/antivirus-scanners-and-sharepoint-farms/)

Answer (score 1):

We use PortalShield 2.0 from McAfee.

Comment: Lisa, what's been your experience with it? Seems like Forefront uses about 800-900 MB of RAM to run its scan engines and needs to be handled carefully during patches and upgrades, but its pretty effective day-to-day and otherwise. What sort of benefits/issues are you seeing w/ McAfee's product?

Answer (score 0):

In many environments the different may be minor, but in other environments like where there is very active high capacity scanning or frequent content moves, it may have more of an impact. It has enough of an impact that we are sure to disable the agents when doing a system migration since it can exponentially increase the processing time.

If you are in a large environment with lots of activity, it is probably worth a performance test with multiple products.