# Sharepoint 2010 virus protection

Tags: anti-virus

I am currently testing MS Forefront Protection 2010 for Sharepoint including management console.
Does anyone have some experience with other sharepoint 2010 protection systems like McAfee, TrendMicro, BitDefender, Avira?

Michael

Comment: You should use MS ForeFront Protection 2010 for SharePoint. I tested other products and some issues with those, such as prevented w3wp.exe in the rule of protection.

Comment: which products did you test? any performance results comparing to forefront?

Comment: @Michael: Welcome to the site! Your question as it stands is a poll which generally we discourage. Can you rephrase the question to be more specific? If not, I can make the question a community wiki.

Comment: Also, as pointed out by @AlexPoint, there is a question which may be interesting to you: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17178/mcafee-security-for-sharepoint-2010

Comment: @Michael : I used ForeFront Protection 2010 for SharePoint to secure collaboration environment. It worked effectively SharePoint collaboration together.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a similar question back in the 2007 timeframe, you may want to take a look at it to get some ideas for points of comparison for the 2010 compatible products: [SharePoint 2007 Antivirus Protection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1563/sharepoint-2007-antivirus-protection)

Answer (score 0):

At my company we use Symantec.  It works well enough and does what is expected of it.  In my opinion, I don't think there is a whole lot of difference between the available AntiVirus solutions for SharePoint.  They scan documents on upload and ones that are already in SharePoint.

Comment: In many environments the different may be minor, but in other environments like where there is very active high capacity scanning or frequent content moves, it may have more of an impact.  It has enough of an impact that we are sure to disable the agents when doing a system migration since it can exponentially increase the processing time.